# Php "echo" function doesn't call script

Tags: php

One quick question about this script; **print_top_ads();** is not calling the script.

Another question about this peace of code. If you want to exclude left and right column of template when $p is loaded (for example to get rid of left_column.php) how could be done.

```
<?php
$pages_dir = 'doc_user';

if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
$pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

$p = $_GET['p'];

if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
}
}   else  
echo "
print_top_ads();
";
?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes. echo is a statement while print is a function (has return result), you are using echo and in title it says print.

Comment: You didn't mean `echo print_top_ads();` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You want `PHP` or `JavaScript` to parse `print_top_ads();`? Please elaborate.

Comment: is print_top_ads() a javascript function you're trying to call? please provide more info.

Comment: @rekire: Not bad, but IMO you masked the OP's confusion too much. Perhaps include that edited code as the start of an answer, showing the OP how reorganising his code would make the error clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to echo the return value of `print_top_ads`:

```
$pages_dir = 'doc_user';

if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
    $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
    unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

    $p = $_GET['p'];

    if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
        include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
    }
}
else  
    echo print_top_ads();
```

Assuming that you are trying to tell JavaScript to execute `print_top_ads`:

```
$pages_dir = 'doc_user';

if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
    $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
    unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

    $p = $_GET['p'];

    if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
        include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
    }
}
else  
    echo "<script>print_top_ads()</script>";
```

Comment: Assuming that you want to echo the return value of print_top_ads: working, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well no, you're just echoing the string. Make the print_top_ads() function echo instead, and just call it.